# How to permanently increase innodb_buffer_pool_size on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, memory, innodb, buffer

I have read lot of posts & manuals to try to find out how to increase memory in MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu, which say there are 3 methods:

1. By editing innodb_buffer_pool_size in the my.cnf
2. By command line option on starting MySQL
3. Dynamically with SQL commands.

I assume 2 and 3 will be lost when MySQL is restarted, which leaves 1.

The problem is, there are no such settings in my /etc/mysql/my.conf.

The string "inno" does not exist in the conf file, nor does "buffer_size" or "buffer-size" (but "key_buffer" is in there).

I installed it via:

```
# apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

Any ideas where I can change the value?

Did I somehow install MySQL without the InnoDB engine?

Am I looking in the wrong file?

There are some other .cnf files under /etc/mysql, but they have nothing like innodb in them either.

```
mysql> show variables like 'inno%'
:
innodb_buffer_pool_size                  | 134217728              |
```

So it looks like InnoDB is installed, I just can't find where its config file is.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what worked for me (ubuntu 19, mysql 8):

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

add in this at the bottom of the file

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 8G
```

save and exit.  restart MySQL.

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is, there are no such settings in my /etc/mysql/my.conf.

So add the lines needed to the `[mysqld]` section of the config file. The default `my.cnf` file only contains a tiny fraction of the configuration values that are available.

Comment: there is strangeness in the syntax of my.cnf.... mostly due to the backwards compatibility of "-" vs "_" and other depricated varnames.... mysql has been around since forever

Comment: THanks EEAA. I actually tried this, although it was guesswork as I cant find a complete example.  I added the line "innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M" directly below the section [mysql], and restarted mysql (service mysql restart). Unfortunately, it made no difference, "show variables" still showed it to be 134217728 = 128MB.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, found it, you have to put the settings under [mysqld].  Not sure why only my install is missing these settings.

Comment: Right, which I mentioned in my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Write these commands in the terminal :

```
root:$cd /etc/mysql/
root:/etc/mysql$ sudo gedit my.cnf
```

Add this at the end of the file (2 GiB)

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2147483648
```

restart apache / mysql

```
root:~$ sudo service mysql restart
root:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: You can simply write `2G` instead of `2147483648`

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS this work for me:

Go to `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`

add this under `[mysql]`:

```
[mysqld]

innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
```

then restart mysql:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Go to mysql to check result:

```
sudo mysql
```

```mysql
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024;
```